# modeling OR relationships?

Tags: database, normalization, entity-relationship, relationships

How do you trasnlate OR relationships in ER diagrams? For example, you have 2 entities that have some connection with the third, but only one of them can have that relation?(ex. *BussinessOwner* or *PrivateOwner* can hold just one *Property*) ?

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 (easier): Two nullable foreign keys, BusinessOwnerID and PrivateOwnerID.

Option 2 (more normalized): Both BusinessOwner and PrivateOwner are Owners, so you could make an Owner entity with whatever information is common between BusinessOwner and PrivateOwner. Then add an OwnerID to both the BusinessOwner and PrivateOwner tables.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

http://consultingblogs.emc.com/davidportas/archive/2007/01/08/Distributed-Keys-and-Disjoint-Subtypes.aspx

Answer (score 0):

User an `owner` and `Type` Field.
Not 2 owner Fields.

Owners are People entity.
Types are Type entity or strings ("Business" Owner or "Private Owner")

What if you add a new type... "Sr. Partner" With your model you would have to add new filed and recode your business rules.